# How can I add a full stop to the end of string, if it's not already there, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a string ends in a full stop, if it doesn't one should be added via vanilla JavaScript. Any ideas?

I was thinking something like this might work to actually see if there is a full stop at the end of the variable, but it seems to error out?

Also at the moment I have no idea how i'd add the full stop to the end of the string.

```
    if todoTitle.str.charAt(str.length-1) != "." {
        alert("doesn't end in .");
    } else {
        alert("does end in .");
    };
```

Any ideas about the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: `'%your_string_there%'.replace(/\.?$/, '.');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition in an `if` clause must be wrapped in parentheses. Also, you refer to your string once as `todoTitle.str` and once as `str`. I assume that only the former is correct? So:

```
    if (todoTitle.str.charAt(todoTitle.str.length-1) != ".") {
        alert("doesn't end in .");
    } else {
        alert("does end in .");
    }
```

(Note that I also removed the inappropriate `;` after the `else` block.

Also, you might want to explicitly check to make sure that `todoTitle.str.length >= 1`.

---

As for actually adding the character: one option is to use your above check, and then write `todoTitle.str = todoTitle.str + '.'`. Another is to combine the check-and-add using the `replace` method:

```
todoTitle.str = todoTitle.str.replace(/([^.])$/, '$1.');
```

This will replace the last character with itself-plus-`.`, provided the last character is not itself `.`.

Comment: Hmm, same issue as an answer above, when I add this I get the error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Which is strange because the variable 'todoTitle is set right above this piece of code.

[edit] same error with `replace` too

Comment: @lucas572: That means that `todoTitle.str` is undefined.

Comment: Yep, but this makes no sense to me, my code literally goes: 

todoTitle = document.getElementById('td-title').value;
todoTitle.str.replace(/([^.])$/, '$1.');`

Comment: @lucas572: I think `document.getElementById('td-title').value` would return a string. JavaScript strings don't have a `str` property. How come you're expecting `todoTitle` to have a `str` property?

Comment: Aaaah, okay my bad. I assumed because it was a string I would have to type `str` to get the string value out of it.

The solution was just to pop `.replace(/([^.])$/, '$1.')` at the end of the variable being set and it worked! Thanks people.

Comment: @lucas572: " I assumed because it was a string I would have to type str to get the string value out of it." That's interesting, where does that idiom come from?

Answer (score 2):

> At the moment I have no idea how i'd add the full stop to the end of the string.

That would be via string concatenation:

```
if (todoTitle.str.charAt(todoTitle.str.length-1) != ".") {
    todoTitle.str = todoTitle.str + "."
}
```

Comment: This sounds like it should be working, but for some reason I'm getting the error: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Strange because the variable 'todoTitle is set right above this piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

If statements need to be in brackets:

```
if (todoTitle.str.charAt(str.length-1) != ".") {
```